# SQL Server : call function passing in bit parameters returns Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Y' to data type bit

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 7 bit elements defined (Form1 - Form7). I need to determine which element contains a value.  The data looks like this:

```
Form1    Form2    Form3    Form4    Form5    Form6    Form7
------------------------------------------------------------
  1        0        0        0        0        0        0 
  0        0        0        1        0        0        0 
  0        0        0        0        0        0        1 
  0        1        0        0        0        0        0
```

I want to call a function which takes in each of these elements and returns an integer value so I can insert the integer value into a new table.

I call my function in an insert comment like this:

```
INSERT INTO [DatabaseName].[dbo].[Table] (FormValue)
    SELECT dbo.fnBuildFormType(a.Form1, a.Form2, a.Form3, a.Form4, a.Form5, a.Form6, a.Form7)
    FROM [DatabaseName].[dbo].[SourceTable] a
```

And this is the code I have in my function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnBuildFormType] 
    (@Form1 bit,
     @Form2 bit,
     @Form3 bit,
     @Form4 bit,
     @Form5 bit,
     @Form6 bit,
     @Form7 bit)
RETURNS integer
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ReturnInteger integer

    IF (@Form1 = 1)
    BEGIN
        SET @ReturnInteger = 1
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        IF (@Form2 = 1)
        BEGIN
            SET @ReturnInteger = 2
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            IF (@Form3 = 1)
            BEGIN
                SET @ReturnInteger = 3
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                IF (@Form4 = 1)
                BEGIN
                    SET @ReturnInteger = 4
                END
                ELSE
                BEGIN
                IF (@Form5 = 1)
                    BEGIN
                    SET @ReturnInteger = 5
                END
                ELSE
                BEGIN
                    IF (@Form6 = 1)
                    BEGIN
                        SET @ReturnInteger = 6
                    END
                    ELSE
                    BEGIN
                        SET @ReturnInteger = 8
                    END
                END
                END
            END
        END
    END
    RETURN @ReturnInteger
END
```

The error message that I get back states SQL Server can not convert the `nvarchar` value `'Y'` to data type bit. The SQL Server table that I am converting originated in MS Access and was converted into a SQL Server table.

When I expand the table in SSMS and look at the definition of Form1 - Form7, it says `(bit, null)` for each.

Any ideas why I would be getting this error message?

Thank you.

UPDATED:

In an effort to simplify this, I have changed my function to look like this:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnBuildFormType] 
    (@FormOther char(1))
RETURNS integer
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ReturnInteger integer

    SET @ReturnInteger = CASE
        WHEN @FormOther = 'Y' THEN 7
        ELSE 0
    END

    RETURN @ReturnInteger
END
```

And I have changed my query to look like this:

```
INSERT INTO [DatabaseName].[dbo].[Table] (FormValue)
    SELECT dbo.fnBuildFormType(a.Form1)
    FROM [DatabaseName].[dbo].[SourceTable] a
```

I am still getting the same error.

Comment: what do you get if you run: select * from [DatabaseName].[dbo].[SourceTable] a ? Y or 1 / 0s.

Comment: @siggemannen: I get an incorrect syntax near ?

Comment: To express a bit in SQL Server either use `0` , `1`, `'true'`, or `'false'` - there is no implicit conversion of `Y`/`N` to `bit`

Comment: ummm. the question  etc. wasn't part of the query :) just run the select from your source table. i suspect it doesn't contain bit fields

Comment: You are selecting `Form1- Form7` but tell us about the definition of `File1 - File7` - these are not the same

Comment: I right clicked on the source table name and started a new query.  I typed in this query: "SELECT * FROM [DatabaseName].[dbo].[SourceTable] a ? Y or 1 / 0s" and I get the incorrect synatx.  I then right clicked on the table name and clicked on design.  When I see the schema of the table, I see "bit" as the Data Type for the elements Form1- Form7

Comment: @MartinSmith Sorry about that.  That was mistyped.  I editied the original post to reflect that the definition of Form1 - Form7 are data type bit.

Comment: what do you get when you right click on the table and select top 1000?? Whats the result?

Comment: @Harry I get a grid of data similar to what I typed at the top of the post.  I see 0's and 1's.

Comment: Does the table you are inserting to have any triggers on it?

Comment: bits can be saved as integer and a simply query can return the active bit , no need for a big table

Comment: I notice that in your sample data, the column `Form2` has the value 2 in one of the rows. Is that a typo? Your function expects the value to be 1 -- or, presumably, 0.

Comment: Check the definition of `Table.FormValue`. Make sure it doesn't have a default value defined. **Make sure no *other* columns in that table have default values incompatible with their definition.** I also think @MartinSmith may be on to something about a trigger being involved.

Comment: if you just run following, does it work? If yes, then there's no triggers. INSERT INTO [DatabaseName].[dbo].[Table] (FormValue)
SELECT 1

Comment: if that doesn't work, then the problem is with your target table

Comment: @siggemannen I ran your suggested query.  1 record gets added to the table with a value of 1 in FormValue.

Comment: ok, then the problem is with your source table. run: select concat(a.Form1, a.form2, a.form3, a.form4, a.form5, a.form6, a.form7) FROM [DatabaseName].[dbo].[SourceTable] a

Comment: it should display 0101010 or something like that

Comment: @siggemannen - Bingo!  There's bad data in the last record of the source table.  I removed that last record and the query runs.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Tricky, glad it got figured out!

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the tbale into a varbinary and then get the bit number quite easyly

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnBuildFormType
(
    @varbin varbinary
)
RETURNS integer
AS
BEGIN
  

    DECLARE @i INT = 0;
    DECLARE @ReturnInteger INT = 0;

        WHILE @i <= 7
        BEGIN
               IF GET_BIT (  @varbin, @i) = 1
                    BEGIN
                      SET @ReturnInteger =  @i + 1  ;
                      BREAK;
                  END 
              SET @i = @i + 1;
        END
    RETURN(@ReturnInteger);
End;
```

```
SELECT dbo.fnBuildFormType(CONVERT(BIGINT,CONVERT(BINARY(7),1 * [Form1] + 10 * [Form2] + 100 * [Form3] +  1000 * [Form4] 
+ 10000 * [Form5] + 100000 * [Form6] +  10000000 * [Form7])))
FROM Table1
```

| (No column name) |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 4 |
| 8 |
| 2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_qgR5lKd)

Answer (score 0):

Well, doing a select, or insert command from VBA, or running/using a stored procedure in SQL server is a Mount Everest of a DIFFERENT question.

but, say this table

```
select * from MachineElements
```

| ID | Form1 | Form2 | Form3 | Form4 | Form5 | Form6 | Form7 | Machine |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | Stamping 1 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | Stamping 2 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | Stamping 2 |
| 4 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | Stamping 3 |

And a query to take the 1-7 values can look like this:

```
select id, Machine,
CASE
   When Form1 > 0 Then 1
   When Form2 > 0 Then 2
   When Form3 > 0 Then 3
   When Form4 > 0 Then 4
   When Form5 > 0 Then 5
   When Form6 > 0 Then 6
   When Form7 > 0 Then 7
   ELSE  8
END as BformType
FROM MachineElements
```

And now we see, get this:

| id | Machine | BformType |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Stamping 1 | 1 |
| 2 | Stamping 2 | 4 |
| 3 | Stamping 2 | 7 |
| 4 | Stamping 3 | 1 |

So, then this:

```
INSERT INTO tblMachineResults
     (ID,MachineName, BformType)
SELECT ID, Machine, 
CASE 
    WHEN Form1 > 0 THEN 1 
    WHEN Form2 > 0 THEN 2 
    WHEN Form3 > 0 THEN 3 
    WHEN Form4 > 0 THEN 4 
    WHEN Form5 > 0 THEN 5 
    WHEN Form6 > 0 THEN 6 
    WHEN Form7 > 0 THEN 7 
    ELSE 8 
END AS BformType
FROM     MachineElements
```

and now in tblMachineResults, we have

```
select * from tblMachineResults
```

And thus this:

| ID | MachineName | BformType |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Stamping 1 | 1 |
| 2 | Stamping 2 | 4 |
| 3 | Stamping 2 | 7 |
| 4 | Stamping 3 | 1 |

so, at this point?

It not clear what the ms-access client part is supposed to do?

However, I can most certainly cut + paste in the above query into the Access query editor, and run it.

We just have to set the query as pass-though, and thus this:

[image]

And since it not supposed to return records, then don't forget this setting in the query sheet:

[image]

So, you are free to run that query from SQL manager, or as above shows, right from inside of Access.